# pypy ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: pypy

Вопрос от начинающего.
С помощью библиотеки Eval7 я написал скрипт необходимых мне расчетов, но он оказался слишком долгим, аж 3 минуты и необходимо это дело ускорить(пока что без оптимизации кода, мне пока сложно всё это дается). Поэтому почитал что pypy в этом может помочь. Скачал, установил, но когда вызываю с командной строки свой скрипт в котором есть import eval7 мне пишет в командной строке что "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named eval7". Хотя eval7 установлена и мой скрипт в IDLE выполняет все три минут успешно и обычные скрипты, без импорта библиотек pypy выполняет.
Подскажите пожалуйста, что я не так сделал или как решить эту проблему? Мне то просто надо проверить ускорит ли pypy мой скрипт или нет.